# Force usage of local "My Games" instead of OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, gaming

I'm trying to play a free copy of Devil May Cry from Twitch Prime. The problem is the game writes save files to `C:\Users\[user]\OneDrive\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection\`, but it wants to read save files from `C:\Users\[user]\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection\`.  This means that to play the game, you have to manually move your save files prior to trying to load. Other players of the Twitch Prime version of the game have the same problem, and no solution has been found.

I was wondering if there is any way to force the save files to be saved to the standard location, rather than the OneDrive location.

Comment: You could try to create a soft link (`mklink`) from one of the directories to the others.

Comment: @Seth Doesn't seem to work. You get the message "can't create file because it already exists". I think they're automatically soft linked.

Comment: If they are you wouldn't have the problem you're describing because doing something on either side would affect the other. You'd need to rename/remove either of the Devil May Cry folder and create a link in its place. If they are already soft link run dir, it would show up as a notation in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Seth suggested, I needed to delete the Devil May Cry folder in One Drive, and then open Command Prompt in Administrator mode (Right Click->Run as Admin). Then type:

```
cd C:\Users\[user]\OneDrive\Documents\My Games\
mklink /d "Devil May Cry HD Collection" "C:\Users\[user]\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection"
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to create the target directory before DmC would be able to save to it. I came up the the following modification to @geokavel's script which has the benefit of preserving any save data that was created in the OneDrive directory as well as utilising environment variables so that it can be pasted on any system without modification.

```
:: MUST BE RUN FROM AN ELEVATED COMMAND PROMPT
:: Moves OneDrive DmC folder and any saves to expected location.
MOVE "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\"
    
:: Creates link from OneDrive DmC folder to actual location.
MKLINK /d "%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection" "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection"
```

And just for good measure, here's a PowerShell version of the same script:

```
# MUST BE RUN FROM ELEVATED POWERSHELL
# Moves OneDrive DmC folder and any saves to expected location.
Move-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection" -Destination "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\My Games\"

# Creates link from OneDrive DmC folder to actual location.
New-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\OneDrive\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection" -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\My Games\Devil May Cry HD Collection"
```